# Ninject cannot bind IRepository<T>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, ninject, 3-tier

I have some problem with my application. Recently I've downloaded Ninject packages and I cannot bind my entities.

My controller:

```
public class ServerController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IServerService _service;

    public ServerController(IServerService service)
    {
        this._service = service;
    }
```

RegisterServices:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IServerService>().To<ServerService>().InSingletonScope();


        kernel.Bind<IRepository<Server>>()
            .To(typeof(ServerRepository))
            .InRequestScope();
    }
```

ServerService:

```
private readonly IRepository<Server> _repository;

    public ServerService(IRepository<Server> repository)
    {
        this._repository = repository;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Server>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await this._repository.GetAllAsync();
    }
```

If someone needs more info I'll send it to comments.

Comment: I got exception: Unable to cast object of type 'HealthCheck.DAL.Framework.Repositories.ServerRepository' to type 'HealthCheck.DAL.Framework.Interfaces.IRepository`1[HealthCheck.DAL.Framework.Models.EnvironmentDbModels.Server]'.

Comment: And another one: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'ServerController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

Comment: The first error message seems to say that `ServerRepository` is not implementing `IRepository<Server>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved. I just added new interfaces to DAL model and implemented IRepository. After that my Ninject register looks like:

```
        kernel.Bind<IServerService>().To<ServerService>().InSingletonScope();
        kernel.Bind<IServerRepository>().To<ServerRepository>().InSingletonScope();
```